# cond with list in Scheme

Tags: list, scheme, lisp, conditional-statements

problem takes a list e.g L = (4 11 16 22 75 34) and gets tested for a condition (modulus 2) then returns a list with all the items in the list that pass the test e.g newL = (4 16 34)

Here is the code:

```
(define clean-list
  (lambda (x)
    (list x (test x))))

(define test
  (lambda (x)
    (cond (= 0 (modulo (car x) 2)) 
          (cons (car x) (test(cdr x)))   
          (else (test(cdr x))))
    ))
```

output:

```
   ((4 11 16 22 75 34) 0)
```

I debugged the code, it foes into (modulo (car x) 2) then returns to clean-list and exits, all after first run, please explain that and why it returns a 0 at the end of list. Also any feedback or improvement in code would be appreciated.

Comment: Your spacing of `(test(cdr x))` suggests that you are thinking about `test` differently than you are thinking about `cons` and `cdr` and the rest.  There is no difference; add a space.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're missing a set of parentheses. You're also missing a test for the recursion bottoming out.

```
(define test
  (lambda (x)
    (cond ((eq? x '()) '())
          ((= 0 (modulo (car x) 2)) 
           (cons (car x) (test(cdr x))))
          (else (test(cdr x))))
    ))
```

[DEMO](http://ideone.com/YslqaD)

The general syntax of `cond` is:

```
(cond (<test1> <result1>)
      (<test2> <result2>)
      ...)
```

In your code `<test1>` was simply `=`, not `(= 0 (modulo (car x) 2))`.

Comment: now the condition module is running fine until the original list is empty then it gives out expected: mpair?, given () error and does not return a list with the elements concatinated

Comment: basically it doesnt stop at empty list(original) status and does not return a list (new list)

Comment: The first test `(eq? x '())` should prevent that. I don't know why it's not working for you, it works in my demo.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a tail-recursive version of the function.

```
(define test
  (lambda (x)

    (define (helper in out)
      (if (null? in)
        out
        (if (= 0 (modulo (car in) 2))
          (helper (cdr in) (append out (list (car in))))
          (helper (cdr in) out))))

    (helper x '())
    ))

(define clean-list
  (lambda (x)
    (list x (test x))))

(write (clean-list '(4 11 16 22 75 34)))
```

The output:

```
((4 11 16 22 75 34) (4 16 22 34))
```

PS. When I tested the code at [repl.it](http://repl.it/languages/Scheme), I had to change `modulo` to `mod`.